# Tiling WM which keeps windows running when not visible

Tags: linux, window-manager, awesome-wm

I've been using awesomewm for a decade or so, and am very comfortable with it. However with the recent Covid-19 changes in working environments I found myself setting up and using OBS as part of my day job (educator).

This brought up a limitation of awesomewm (and tiling WMs in general? I'm not sure) which is that OBS can only receive updates from running windows, and when the tag of a window is hidden, the window is effectively minimized (not sure about the correct terminology here, but for example an mpv window would still be playing the audio but OBS would not receive any graphical updates).

Are there any other Tiling WMs which allow tags-like behaviour (all of them I'd think) but where windows would still be effectively running under other windows such that OBS can pick up their graphical updates?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run a compositing manager like Picom or Compton to enable that. It is an X11 limitation. Since most tiling window manager are not bundled with a compositor, they all behave like this. Thankfully, it's just because all of those WMs favor external compositors rather than built-in ones like Gnome and KDE.

Comment: Actually that doesn't help, I've just tested with compton and OBS does not update if the window is in another tag (at least for awesomewm)

Comment: You might need to make a feature request there. AwesomeWM has no control over the client rendering.